# Toggle and Refresh Page Synchronization in View

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, timer

I have a query: I want to toggle between two Views through single controller. The toggling works fine 10 sec interval is set for it. But when I try to Refresh my whole page. The synchronization between Toggling interval and Refresh Page interval is disturbed(not smooth). Also, when page is refreshed the Default View comes up for a blink of an eye and then the second View shows for 10 sec (I mean random/arbitrary toggle).

How to get the two intervals(Toggle + refresh) sync properly ?

[image: Html code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery is beauty**. It was a simple logic change and few commands in jquery which did the work great. Downloaded the jquery bundle and added its reference within script Tag in my Html View's header.
Simply replace the javascript functions with following for Toggling between two Views after 5 seconds:

```
    function ToggleFunction() {
        $('#View2').hide();
        myVar = setTimeout(SecondView, 5000);

    }
    function SecondView()
    {
        $('#View1').hide();
        $('#View2').show();
    }
```

The Refresh after 20 minutes was handled in my controller by simply adding following line of code:

```
 Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "20");
```